# How to change the default file association for a file with "nothing better" assigned?

Tags: finder, mojave

The default file association for an unrecognized file extension is TextEdit. I'd rather it use Emacs. How can this be changed? High-Sierra and Mojave, if it makes a difference.

Note: This is not about changing the default for a given file-type. I'm asking about the fall-back for any file that has no assigned default.

> What do you mean by unrecognised file type?

That description was perhaps misleading; I've updated the title.
A couple of examples from my files are 'a.out', "#AtoD.ino#", "cookies.sqlite". BTW, I'm not asking what these files are, where they came from, or why they don't have a file-association that plays nicely. I'd just like to choose which tool opens them by default.

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate but I can't remember what to search for. I do know Apple broke this as it was easy on NeXT. I think the current answer is that you cannot (and I find another reason why I use Path Finder)

Comment: What do you mean by _unrecognised file type_?  Can you give an example?